# When I post text with media on Facebook, the text does not show

Tags: facebook

I want to post text with text and image or video on Facebook but in these cases the text is not being posted, only the image or video is being posted. What is the solution? If I post an image and then add text to it, the text does not show. If you look at the edit history of the post, you can see that "1 attachment is not displayed" is written[image]